# Validity of Ising model for mean field thoery

Tags: magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, approximations, ising-model, spin-models

The Heisenberg model for the Hamiltonian of a ferromagnet is given by:
$$H=-\frac{J}{2} \sum \vec{S}_i\cdot \vec{S}_j+\mu_B B \sum_i S^z_i$$
when performing mean field theory, to find $\chi$, we assume that the Ising model holds, i.e. take a Hamiltonian to be:

$$H=-\frac{J}{2} \sum S^z_i S^z_j+\mu_B B \sum_i S^z_i$$

My question is why when using mean field theory is it applicable to use the Ising model?

Comment: [Any trial Hamiltonian will do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_free_energy#Bogoliubov_inequality)